# How to pass two values to _between operator?

Tags: directus

"You must specify 2 values for the whereBetween clause" BUT how?

I am currently using the version: 9.0.0-rc.42

**Error message**   "The filter value for "_between" has to be a string, number, or boolean"

```js
filter: {
          date: {
            _between: ["2021-01-24", "2021-02-23"],
          },
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is correct, there was a bug in Directus' query validation for the `_between` operator (fixed in [5908822](https://github.com/directus/directus/commit/5908822ea9a545b9b464087b7da9927aca6a4df2), released in v9.0.0-rc.43).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the value as comma seperated string.

```
_between: "2021-01-24,2021-02-23"
```